PiVPN & OpenVpn, won't connect on local network
I have been searching trying to find a solution for this and very grateful for your assistance. As the (rudimentary) diagram below shows, I live on a farm which has two houses each of which has their own network (subnet?). From the 10.124.0.0/24 I can ping the 192.168.0.1/24 network which suggests they are both subnets.
I am trying to set up a PiVPN on the 10.124.0.0/24 network so I can connect remotely. The setup is fine and I can ping the raspberry pi, however, when I attempt to connect using OpenVPN from either a) within the 10.124 network or b) tethered to an LTE hotspot to simulate an external connection - OpenVPN does not connect. I have been going round and round trying to solve this but cannot get it to function.
I'm not sure what the issue is but very grateful for any assistance and will try to provide logs as necessary.
Cisco Network Diagram


the diagram shows two LANs connected to the internet ... they could be in separate cities

In your diagram you connect both routers where they are also connected to the internet. Is that correct?
If they are really connected over the internet, then you should use the routers to establish the VPN (ok, of cause only if they provide VPN functionallity).
If you need the internal VPN(s) [if your router do not provide VPN functionallity] then you need two internal VPN-Nodes (RasPi in your example), one in each internal network. Both must be connected over the (internet) external Networkadresses (provided by the ISP). Then you also have to deal with NAT to get the external access into the internal network. And the things get even more complicated if you only have dynamic IP addresses (DynDNS?) or stacked IPV6 adresses on the WAN side.
The best case scenario would be, if you can connect (or even have connected)  both routers directly. Then you don't need VPN.
In any case, that is not a question that can be shortly answered here. It is also not a Raspi question. Perhaps you can ask in the network community.
Although my answer is a bit confusing (it's late and I'm not a network Guru and no native english speaker;-)), I hope I could give you some ideas you can think about or work with. I just answered, because I saw no one else did yet. Perhaps you get a better answer from some else.
